# Inserting redundant data in DB

Tags: java, mysql, swing, excel

I was given a task on fetching data from Excel sheet and updating in MySQL database, which has 2 columns USN and Name. The problem is USN is printing in both the rows as well as the name. For example if there are 12 records when I save it in DB it will insert 24 records. I am using Swing concept as well. Below is my code.

```
class OpenClass implements ActionListener 
{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    Workbook w ;
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
  JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

  int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(ExcelFileUploading.this);
  if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
  {       
      try 
      {
        w = Workbook.getWorkbook(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
        for(int i = 0; i<sheet.getRows(); i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<sheet.getColumns();j++)
            {
                Cell cell = null;
                if(j==0)
                {
                    cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                    if(checkIfNumber(cell.getContents().toString())== false)
                    {
                        //System.out.print("\t\t");
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
                cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                CellType type = cell.getType();

                if((type == CellType.LABEL)|| (type == CellType.NUMBER))
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        Class.forName(driver);
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,username,password);
                        stmt = con.createStatement();
                        String query = "INSERT INTO student (USN,Name)"
                            +"VALUES('"+cell.getContents()+"','"+cell.getContents()+"')";
                        stmt.executeUpdate(query);

                    } catch (Exception exp) 
                     {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                     }
                    finally
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            stmt.close();
                            con.close();
                        } catch (SQLException exp) 
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      } catch (Exception exp)
    {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
      display.setText("Opened File : " +((chooser.getSelectedFile()!=null)?
              chooser.getSelectedFile().getName(): "nothing"));
  }

  if(option == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) 
  {
      display.setText("Open Operation Cancelled");
  }
}

private boolean checkIfNumber(String string) 
{
    try 
    {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(string);
        //System.out.print(d);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ne) 
    {
        return false;
    }

}
 }
```

Since there are 2 columns in the my Db table(USN, Name) I had to put `cell.getContents()` twice.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: how are you reading the excel file? my guess is that you are reading the excel file wrong. also use prepared statement for DB queries

Comment: Reading everything is proper bcz if i print in console its printing as i want. where as if i insert into Db it gives the above problem

Comment: Could you show us a small example of your excell sheet? How many columns? what is the content?

Comment: I could have uploaded the image but not couldn't. Its k my excel sheet has 2 columns one column USN another column Name

Comment: @Rithesh : One note. you are creating a separate connection for every iteration in a loop. that's too heavy performance wise

Comment: You got your iterations all wrong. For each cell you make an insert, while you should make an insert for each row. Remove the inner loop and perform change your insert so that it take the content of first and second column.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet you are telling about the for loop ie (for j=0;)

Comment: @Rithesh This is basic algorithm logic: `for each row: insert in table (content of first colum, content of second column`. What you are doing is: `for each cell insert in table (content of cell, content of cell)`. These are very different things.

Comment: Your algorithm logic is incorrect and does not correspond to what you describe. If you want to skip headers, simply check if content of first or second column in the current row is a header or not. If yes, then just skip it.

Comment: In the Excel  Sheet there around 255 records and some headers in between in order to remove those headers i have written that loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your iterating over all rows within the excel and then over all columns in the excel.
Your using 2 columns you don't need the second loop.
Also, you have only one Cell object and keep only one reference to a cell, but when you create the insert statement you assign the same cell for both values in the SQL

So if you have 2 rows (columns separated with "," character:

- 1,11
- 2,22

Your SQL statements are:

```
INSERT INTO student (USN,Name)VALUES('1','1')
INSERT INTO student (USN,Name)VALUES('11','11')

INSERT INTO student (USN,Name)VALUES('2','2')
INSERT INTO student (USN,Name)VALUES('12','12')
```

What you want is something like this in which for each row we:

1. Check the first cell to see if it is a string and if so assign to cell1.
2. Check the second cell to see if it appropriate type. Go to next row and step 1 if not.
3. Create the SQL statement using Cell1 and Cell2.

So, without the actual mysql connection/insertion I think your looking more for something like this:

```
public class OpenClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new OpenClass().testIt();
    }

    public void testIt() {
        Workbook w;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

        int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        //CREATE TWO CELL OBJECTS
        Cell cell1, cell2;
        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                w = Workbook.getWorkbook(chooser.getSelectedFile());

                Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);

                //ITERATE BY ROWS
                for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {

                    //GET AND CHECK COLUMN1 VALUE
                    cell1 = sheet.getCell(0, i);
                    if (checkIfNumber(cell1.getContents().toString()) == false)
                        continue;

                    //GET CHECK COLUMN2 VALUE
                    cell2 = sheet.getCell(1, i);
                    CellType type = cell2.getType();

                    if ((type == CellType.LABEL) || (type == CellType.NUMBER)) {
                        String query = "INSERT INTO student (USN,Name)"
                                + "VALUES('" + cell1.getContents() + "','"
                                + cell2.getContents() + "')";
                        System.out.println(query);
                        //RUN YOUR QUERY HERE!
                    }
                }
            } catch (BiffException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private boolean checkIfNumber(String string) {
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(string);
            //System.out.print(d);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Finally, the connection should only be created once to the database due to extended overhead. The jexcelapi library code worked perfectly with your code so you must be using that library.